# How to get private data from public section in a rails multi tenancy application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am building multitenancy app in rails. Using PgTools.

I have stored data in movies table in public section if i want to access same data in private section ie: Example is subdomain which is defined as private section in which i want to acess movies table.

```
[3] pry(main)> PgTools.restore_default_search_path
=> "\"$user\", public"
[4] pry(main)> Movie.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "movies"
=> 6
[5] pry(main)> PgTools.set_search_path "example", false
=> "example"
[6] pry(main)> Movie.count
   (163.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "movies"
=> 0
[7] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 1):

To Achieve this if you are not using the appartment gem which gives you the flexibility of excluding certain models from your private schema even without you can achieve this by using

```
    PgTools.restore_default_search_path
```

switch to the public tenant first

```
    movie_count = Movie.count
```

store the count in a variable then switch back and use the variable

```
    PgTools.set_search_path "example", false
```

k will still have the value or you can also store the whole of the active record object if you want to perform any operation on that.